# reverse a string using character arrays and recursion, some Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: c++, arrays, string, recursion, char

I'm trying to reverse a string using character arrays and recursion but I get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)" the compiler asks for about 7 inputs and then starts asking for commands, whereas it should ask for input once and then print the answer on the next line. The program runs fine when I use loops, it starts doing weird things when I use recursion.

```
char* reverse(char ss[30], int l){
    char *p = new char;
    int c=0;
    if(c!=l+1){
        p[c]=ss[l-c-1];
        c++;
        reverse(ss, l);
    }
    return p;
} 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    char ss[30];
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        ss[i]=s[i];
    }
    char *answer;
    answer=reverse(ss, s.length());
    cout<<answer<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many characters does `char *p = new char;` allocate for `p`? Is it sufficient for `p[c]=ss[l-c-1];` to be writing to valid memory?

Comment: when you function stop it recursif processing ?! probably never ...

Comment: @Landstalker That looks about right: the function changes neither `ss` nor `l`, so it can't help but attempt an infinite recursion.

Comment: Remember that your variable c is local for each instance of reverse function you call. If you always assign 0 to c (int c=0;) you will calling reverse indefinitely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first we read the input from the user and store it in a string called s;
we get the size add put it in a char array (after all a char array can be thought of as a string), the extra one is just for the '\0' character.
next I pass it into the reverse function and then print out the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    unsigned int StringSz = s.length();
    char arr[StringSz+1];
    arr[StringSz] = '\0';
    reverse(arr,s);
    cout << arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Now how does our function works?

We pass the array, the string and the position we are currently in, then we switch the first element with the last element, we switch the second element with the one before the last and do this until we reach the end of the string.

```
void reverse(char* arr,string& s,int start=0)
{
    if(start==s.length())
        return;
    arr[start] = s[s.length()-start-1];
    reverse(arr,s,start+1);

}
```

Comment: why `arr[StringSz] = '\0';` you already done `{0}`. You change lot function prototype ;)

Comment: @Landstalker there's a difference between
     char arr[StringSz+1] = {0}; &
    arr[StringSz] = '\0';
at least that's what i know because I'm self taught

Comment: This answer would be helped dramatically by a bit of explanation. Right now it's pretty much a code-dump, and those have an unfortunate tendency to teach [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Explain what you did, why, and how it solved the problem the asker had.

Comment: Try to avoid non-Standard code like `char arr[StringSz+1] = {0};` in answers because it doesn't apply to too many compilers. That's a Variable Length Array. In all of the cases I've seen them allowed by extension, they are Automatic allocations and do not need to be manually destroyed. `delete[] arr;` is at best wrong and could be fatal.

Comment: Try to keep answers simple. `*(arr+start) = s[s.length()-start-1];` could be `arr[start] = s[s.length()-start-1];` Plus if you're going to operate on a std::string`, you might as well stick with `std::string` and take advantage of `std::reverse`

Comment: @user4581301 hope this is better, and second i didnt use the standard library because the question was how to do it using recursions!

Comment: Program still invokes Undefined Behaviour with `delete[] arr;`

Comment: @aliberro thank you so much. Your code works perfectly and I understand it too.

Comment: @AniketVishwakarma could you atleast upvote it, if that's ok

Comment: @user4581301 what do you mean by unknown behavior its working fine i debugged it and nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: The most terrifying thing about Undefined Behaviour is sometimes it looks like it works. `char arr[StringSz+1];` is allocated in Automatic storage (probably a stack). `delete[] arr;` will try to return an Automatic allocation to the Free Store (probably a heap) and that is not allowed. Exactly what happens if you break this rule is not defined by the C++ Standard, so the implementors can do anything from totally ignore you did it, to emit a warning that you shouldn't have done it, to raise an error at run time, to crash, to the completely fantastical or farcical.

Comment: Since `arr` is automatically allocated, it will be automatically released. You didn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion using recursion is - always better to replace with a loop

You set C++ tag - lets use std::string

This a one code wiv 2 method - loop and recursion

1) Loop - func ReverseStr

2) Recursion - func ReverseStrRecusrsion

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string ReverseStrRecusrsion(std::string s, std::size_t pos = 0) { 

    std::swap(s[pos], s[s.length() - pos - 1]);
    if (pos < s.length() /2) {
        s = ReverseStrRecusrsion(s, ++pos);
    }

    return s;
} 


std::string ReverseStr(std::string s) { 

    std::size_t size{s.length()}; 
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        std::swap(s[i], s[size - i - 1]); 
    }

    return s;
} 



int main() { 

    std::string str = "teststring";
    auto new_str{ReverseStr(str)}; 
    auto new_str2{ReverseStrRecusrsion(new_str)};

    std::cout << "old str " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "new str " << new_str << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "rev new str " << new_str2 << std::endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```